# PANDAS group by with 30 minute intervals and calculate total difference

Tags: python, pandas, p-lang

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| date | week | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/07/21 12:46:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 20/07/21 12:56:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 20/07/21 13:09:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 20/07/21 14:11:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 20/07/21 14:42:00 | 1 | d1 |

I want to group by date in in 30 minutes interval- so if 2 consecutive rows are more than 30 minutes apart they are on different groups.
The output I need looks like this:

| week | id | min_date | max_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d1 | 20/07/21 12:46:00 | 20/07/21 13:09:00 |
| 1 | d1 | 20/07/21 14:11:00 | 20/07/21 14:11:00 |
| 1 | d1 | 20/07/21 14:42:00 | 20/07/21 14:42:00 |

I used this code in order to group by:

```
x=df.groupby(['id','week', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='30min',origin="start")]).agg({'date':[np.min, np.max]})
```

Something isn't working with the grouper, any suggestions how to improve it?

EDIT:

Here's an example of my data that causes an issue:

| date | week | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20/07/21 12:46:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 20/07/21 12:56:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 20/07/21 13:09:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 22/07/21 07:11:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 22/07/21 07:14:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 22/07/21 07:27:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 22/07/21 08:34:00 | 1 | d1 |
| 22/07/21 08:36:00 | 1 | d1 |

The output required is:

| week | id | min_date | max_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d1 | 20/07/21 12:46:00 | 20/07/21 13:09:00 |
| 1 | d1 | 20/07/21 07:11:00 | 20/07/21 07:27:00 |
| 1 | d1 | 20/07/21 08:34:00 | 20/07/21 08:36:00 |

This is the output I get:

| week | id | min_date | max_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | d1 | 20/07/21 12:46:00 | 20/07/21 13:09:00 |
| 1 | d1 | 20/07/21 07:11:00 | 20/07/21 08:36:00 |

I don't understand why it groups the last rows together when there is more than an hour difference between 20/07/21 07:27:00 and 20/07/21 08:34:00.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

(df.groupby(df['date'].diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('30min')).cumsum())
 ['date'].agg(['min', 'max'])
)
```

Or maybe also group by id and week:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

(df.groupby(['week', 'id', df['date'].diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('30min')).cumsum()])
 ['date'].agg(['min', 'max'])
  .droplevel(-1).reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   week  id                 min                 max
0     1  d1 2021-07-20 12:46:00 2021-07-20 13:09:00
1     1  d1 2021-07-20 14:11:00 2021-07-20 14:11:00
2     1  d1 2021-07-20 14:42:00 2021-07-20 14:42:00
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping! after checking the code on my data I see that in some cases the grouping doesn't work, it groups together rows that are 40 minutes or an hour apart, when I need separation of 30 minutes- if 2 rows are 30 minutes or plus apart so this will be a new group. Can you please help me understand the issue?

Comment: Make sure the data is first sorted by `date`: `df = df.sort_values(by='date')`

Comment: It is sorted, and still have the same problem. anything else I can check?

Comment: Can you try to provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue? Have you checked that the date conversion is correct (you have an ambiguous format)?

Comment: @kri I am sorry but when I try your new example I get exactly what you expect (3 rows)

Comment: Here is a reproducible input: `from pandas import Timestamp ; df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [Timestamp('2021-07-20 12:46:00'), Timestamp('2021-07-20 12:56:00'), Timestamp('2021-07-20 13:09:00'), Timestamp('2021-07-22 07:11:00'), Timestamp('2021-07-22 07:14:00'), Timestamp('2021-07-22 07:27:00'), Timestamp('2021-07-22 08:34:00'), Timestamp('2021-07-22 08:36:00')], 'week': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'id': ['d1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1', 'd1']})`